# Custom "file lists" in Netbeans?

Tags: model-view-controller, netbeans

I use Netbeans mostly for PHP web development using an [MVC framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

When using the MVC pattern, there tends to be files which are related, but in different directories. For example, if I were building a blog website and wanted to work on the Post object, I would be going back and forth between the Post model class file, the PostController class file, and various view files. Even though you become quick about it, hunting around for them feels repetitious and inefficient. To go from working on one object to another often will involve closing 4-5 files related to the former, and then opening 4-5 files in different directories related to the latter.

I think it would be great if I could make "file lists", similar to a music playlist. That is, I could add all the files related to each object to a list, and then select that list any time I want to open/close those files. For example, I could click the list named "Post", and Post.php, PostController.php, etc. all open automatically.

Is there any such feature available in Netbeans?